# What is the difference between "Consent to application" and "Add delegated permission grant"?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I've been exploring Azure Active Directory audit logs sent to my SIEM, and noticed there are events of type `Consent to Application` as well as `Add delegated permission grant`. I'm not sure what the difference is - I thought granting consent to an app was all about granting it delegated permissions?

As a concrete example, here are two such events that were fired for the same user at the same time (rounded to a second), with the same `correlationId` - so presumably they happened as part of the same "flow". I removed some irrelevant fields and also tokenized GUIDs and such.

Here's the `Consent to Application` event:

```
{
    "Actor": [
        {"ID": "name@corp.com", "Type": 5},
        {"ID": "Actor_PUID" "Type": 3},
        {"ID": "User_guid_user", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "guid_user", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "User", "Type": 2}
    ],
    "ActorContextId": "guid_actor_context_id",
    "AzureActiveDirectoryEventType": 1,
    "CreationTime": "2020-04-28T11:51:30",
    "ExtendedProperties": [
        {"Name": "actorContextId", "Value": "guid_actor_context_id"},
        {"Name": "actorObjectId", "Value": "guid_user"},
        {"Name": "actorObjectClass", "Value": "User"},
        {"Name": "actorUPN", "Value": "name@corp.com"},
        {"Name": "actorPUID", "Value": "Actor_PUID"},
        {"Name": "targetContextId", "Value": "guid_actor_context_id"},
        {"Name": "targetObjectId", "Value": "guid_target_object"},
        {"Name": "extendedAuditEventCategory", "Value": "ServicePrincipal"},
        {"Name": "targetSPN", "Value": "guid_target_spn"},
        {"Name": "targetName", "Value": "App Name"},
        {
            "Name": "targetIncludedUpdatedProperties",
            "Value": "[\"ConsentContext.IsAdminConsent\",\"ConsentContext.IsAppOnly\",\"ConsentContext.OnBehalfOfAll\",\"ConsentContext.Tags\",\"ConsentAction.Permissions\",\"TargetId.ServicePrincipalNames\"]"
        }
    ],
    "Id": "guid_id",
    "ModifiedProperties": [
        {
            "Name": "ConsentAction.Permissions",
            "NewValue": "[] => [[Id: XXX, ClientId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, PrincipalId: guid_user, ResourceId: guid_resource_id, ConsentType: Principal, Scope:  openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite]]; ",
            "OldValue": ""
        },
        {"Name": "TargetId.ServicePrincipalNames", "NewValue": "guid_target_spn", "OldValue": ""}
    ],
    "ObjectId": "guid_target_spn",
    "Operation": "Consent to application.",
    "RecordType": 8,
    "ResultStatus": "Success",
    "Target": [
        {"ID": "ServicePrincipal_guid_target_object", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "guid_target_object", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "ServicePrincipal", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "App Name", "Type": 1},
        {"ID": "guid_target_spn", "Type": 2},
        {ID": "guid_target_spn", "Type": 4}
    ],
    "TargetContextId": "guid_actor_context_id",
}
```

This presumably means that the user with object ID `guid_user` (and an identical principal ID) grants `App Name` with service principal `guid_target_spn` permission to access resource `guid_resource_id` with the delegated permissions `openid offline_access Calendars.ReadWrite`.

Now, here's the `Add delegated permission grant`:

```
{
    "Actor": [
        {"ID": "user@corp.com", "Type": 5},
        {"ID": "user_puid", "Type": 3},
        {"ID": "User_user_guid", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "user_guid", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "User", "Type": 2}
    ],
    "ActorContextId": "guid_actor_context_id",
    "CreationTime": "2020-04-28T11:51:30",
    "ExtendedProperties": [
        {"Name": "actorContextId", "Value": "guid_actor_context_id"},
        {"Name": "actorObjectId", "Value": "user_guid"},
        {"Name": "actorObjectClass", "Value": "User"},
        {"Name": "actorUPN", "Value": "user@corp.com"},
        {"Name": "actorPUID", "Value": "user_puid"},
        {"Name": "targetContextId", "Value": "guid_actor_context_id"},
        {"Name": "targetObjectId", "Value": "guid_resource_id"},
        {"Name": "extendedAuditEventCategory", "Value": "ServicePrincipal"},
        {
            "Name": "targetSPN",
            "Value": "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us;https://graph.microsoft.com/;https://graph.microsoft.us;https://canary.graph.microsoft.com;https://graph.microsoft.com;https://ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000;Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService"
        },
        {"Name": "targetName", "Value": "Microsoft Graph"},
        {
            "Name": "targetIncludedUpdatedProperties",
            "Value": "[\"ServicePrincipal.ObjectID\",\"ServicePrincipal.DisplayName\",\"ServicePrincipal.AppId\",\"ServicePrincipal.Name\",\"TargetId.ServicePrincipalNames\"]"
        },
        {
            "Name": "additionalTargets",
            "Value": "[{\"ObjectID\":\"guid_target_object\",\"DisplayName\":null,\"ObjectClass\":\"ServicePrincipal\",\"AppId\":null,\"Name\":null}]"
        },
    ],
    "ModifiedProperties": [
        {"Name": "ServicePrincipal.ObjectID", "NewValue": "guid_target_object", "OldValue": ""},
        {"Name": "ServicePrincipal.DisplayName", "NewValue": "", "OldValue": ""},
        {"Name": "ServicePrincipal.AppId", "NewValue": "", "OldValue": ""},
        {"Name": "ServicePrincipal.Name", "NewValue": "", "OldValue": ""},
        {
            "Name": "TargetId.ServicePrincipalNames",
            "NewValue": "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us;https://graph.microsoft.com/;https://graph.microsoft.us;https://canary.graph.microsoft.com;https://graph.microsoft.com;https://ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000;Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService",
            "OldValue": ""
        }
    ],
    "ObjectId": "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us;https://graph.microsoft.com/;https://graph.microsoft.us;https://canary.graph.microsoft.com;https://graph.microsoft.com;https://ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000;Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService",
    "Operation": "Add delegated permission grant.",
    "OrganizationId": "guid_actor_context_id",
    "RecordType": 8,
    "ResultStatus": "Success",
    "SupportTicketId": "",
    "Target": [
        {"ID": "ServicePrincipal_guid_resource_id", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "guid_resource_id", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "ServicePrincipal", "Type": 2},
        {"ID": "Microsoft Graph", "Type": 1},
        {"ID": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", "Type": 2},
        {
            "ID": "https://dod-graph.microsoft.us;https://graph.microsoft.com/;https://graph.microsoft.us;https://canary.graph.microsoft.com;https://graph.microsoft.com;https://ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000/ags.windows.net;00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000;Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService",
            "Type": 4
        }
    ],
    "TargetContextId": "guid_actor_context_id",
    "UserId": "user@corp.com",
    "UserKey": "user_puid@corp.com",
}
```

I'm trying to make sense of all of this. Specifically -

1) What does the second event mean? How come it says it's about delegating a permission, but there's no mention of what that permission is? Clearly this is related to the same resource ID as the first call, but in what way? Does it grant `Microsoft Graph` access to the same resource (and if so, under which permissions)?

2) In the first call, what is `guid_target_object`? Does it represent the app ID? If so, why does it appear as `ServicePrincipal_guid_target_object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the audit logs navigate to Enterprise applications -> Audit logs in the portal.

When you add *delegated permission*(e.g. Microsoft Graph -> delegated permission) and then click the button `grant admin consent for xxx`, these four audit logs will be sent:
[image]

The two calls that you mentioned happen at the same time. 
**Add delegated permission grant**'s targets are Microsoft Graph and the application which add permission. 
**Consent to application**'s target is just the application. 
They are two steps in a process.

**Update:**

From my test results, `add a delegated permission` just sends *update application* and *update service principal*. The two logs you mentioned are sent when clicking the button(grant admin consent for xxx), and they are sent at the same time. It is decided by Microsoft.

If you want to know the permissions, you could find them in *update application -> Modified Properties*.

The id is the `resource id` of the permission in Microsoft graph:
[image]

You can get the value of the permission with the Powershell:

```
(Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <object-id of the MS Graph in your tenant>).Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq '570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca'}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing this from the portal's perspective! I'm struggling to understand the meaning of each of these logs. Will they always fire in tandem (e.g. also when adding additional permissions to an app to which a consent was already granted, etc.)? If the scope (delegated permissions) is part of the _Consent to application_ event, then what does _Add delegated permission grant_ represent? What additional information can I extract from it?